# Change Field Setting Value Programmatically in Orchard

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I am trying to modify a fields setting when the field gets updated in the admin UI. Is there a way to do this without creating a ContentDefinitionEditorEventsBase Class?

Here is the update method for the field, I'd like to be able to update the fields settings as well (The field setting called Version seen below). This method gets called after a content item with this field is saved.

```
 protected override DriverResult Editor(ContentPart part, DefaultTextField field, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {

        DefaultTextFieldSettings settings = field.PartFieldDefinition.Settings.GetModel<DefaultTextFieldSettings>();

        var viewModel = new DefaultTextFieldDriverViewModel
        {
            Field = field,
            Text = field.Value,
            Settings = settings
        };

        if (updater.TryUpdateModel(viewModel, GetPrefix(field, part), null, null))
        {
            if (viewModel.Settings.Required && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(viewModel.Text))
            {
                updater.AddModelError("Text", T("The field {0} is mandatory", T(field.DisplayName)));
                return ContentShape("Fields_Common_DefaultText_Edit", GetDifferentiator(field, part),
                                    () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(TemplateName: "Fields.Common.DefaultText.Edit", Model: viewModel, Prefix: GetPrefix(field, part)));
            }

            if (string.Compare(field.Value, viewModel.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCulture) != 0)
            {
                settings.Version++;
            }

            field.Value = viewModel.Text;
        }

        return Editor(part, field, shapeHelper);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's the scenario?

Comment: Once I save a content item and if that field's value has changed I am trying to update that fields setting in the fields Driver

Comment: I added the code from the driver for reference.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how that makes sense: the settings are at the type level, and the driver acts at the item level. I don't see what you would achieve by changing settings every time any item of that type is updated. It looks at best like an abuse of settings.

Comment: Gotcha, I ended up storing it on the field instead.